# Execute Javascript when the registration form is completed

Tags: users, social-network

I am running Facebook advertising campaign for my site. The below code needs to be executed when registration is completed. 
How can I achieve this?

```
<script>
// Track when a registration form is completed (ex. complete subscription, sign up for a service)
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add callback for the form submission. Something like this

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#form_id'] == 'your_form_id') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_callback';
  }
}

function custom_callback() {
  drupal_set_message('This is my custom message');
}
```

Now, after the form submission, the `custom_callback` will also be executed.

If the code is Javascript and the form submission is via Ajax, you may have a look at the [Ajax framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) and [Ajax framework commands](http://Ajax%20framework%20commands) topics in the API documentation. [How to execute custom javascript code after an ajax succes (using the Drupal Ajax framework) ?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1028410) is another useful page/

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user on specific page after registration and this js-code should be inserted on this page.

Comment: How can i redirect user ?

Comment: `$form_state['redirect'] = 'path';` in you submit callback.